# How to Override Protocol for RewriteRules

Tags: apache, redirect, mod-rewrite, https, url-scheme

I am running IBM HTTP Server (based on Apache version 2.2, unfortunately) to host several domains. For these domains, thousands of handwritten RewriteRules have accumulated over the years. These rules live inside site-specific configuration files that are Included in both VirtualHost sections for each site, once for port 80 and once for port 443.

The web servers are not connected directly to the internet. Instead, there is a load balancer in front of them which also terminates SSL connections. That means I have "SSLEngine off" in the VirtualHosts for port 443. Requests that were sent via HTTPS on port 443 still arrive at the web servers on port 443, just unencrypted.

Most of the RewriteRules have the following form:

```
RewriteRule ^/some-path/$  /some-other-path [L,R=301]
```

What I now found out is that these redirects are always broken when /somepath is called via HTTPS. Example:

```
wget --max-redirect=0 -S --spider https://example.com/some-path
...
Location: http://example.com:443/some-other-path
```

As you can see, the user is redirected to HTTP on port 443 which, unsurprisingly, does not work with most clients. Google Chrome apparently tries the right thing, but curl, wget, Firefox and Internet Explorer fail (and rightly so).

I know how I could detect the proper protocol and rewrite all RewriteRules to do the right thing. The problem is that I want to avoid doing that, if at all possible. I am talking about more than 8,000 rules of different forms in a more or less "free" format. While I am fairly proficient in using Vim, I expect to create a lot of errors that will lead to more work.

Is there any way I can force the protocol for RewriteRules without specifying the protocol in the rules themselves?

The only way I found was to remove the L option in all rules and just have a "last" rule for all sites that fixes the protocol. But I am unsure whether that will lead to unforeseen effects since I strongly assume that some redirect targets will then match later RewriteRules.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try :

```
RewriteRule ^/some-path/$  https://example.com/some-other-path [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Sure, that would work. But my point is that I want to avoid changing 8,000+ RewriteRules.